# Cannot install Docker on Ubuntu Snappy on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker

I use `ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-raspi2.img` on Raspberry Pi2.

I performed `sudo snappy update` then rebooted.

Now I wanted to install `docker` and get a "package not found" error. The following is the trace:

```
(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ snappy search docker
Name   Version   Summary
docker 1.6.2.005 Docker

(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install docker
Installing docker
docker failed to install: snappy package not found

(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy list -u
Name        Date       Version
ubuntu-core 2016-02-25 10
webdm       2016-01-28 0.11
pi2         2016-03-02 0.17
(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$
```

A short discussion on mailing list with the only [other reference](https://www.mail-archive.com/snappy-devel@lists.ubuntu.com/msg01153.html) to this problem suggested network connectivity, however in my case the update finished succesfully and I had no problems installing other packages:

```
(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install dnsmasq-arm.howy
Installing dnsmasq-arm.howy
Starting download of dnsmasq-arm
1.09 MB / 1.09 MB [===================================================================================] 100.00 % 403.78 KB/s
Done
Starting download of icon for package
54.73 KB / 54.73 KB [=================================================================================] 100.00 % 108.36 KB/s
Done
```

I also found no problems installing `docker` in `ubuntu/ubuntu-core-devel-amd64` Vagrant box, which would point to `armhf` architecture as the culprit, but [this article](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/using-snappy/) suggests it should work.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store was going on some issues at the time you wrote this (alias were not installable), do not hesitate to jump on IRC/check on the ML for this kind of temporary issues (sorry about this!), but I confirm everything you type is correct.

Comment: Indeed the same procedure works now. Would you be willing to extend your answer and provide the exact channel name or mailing list address, web address? Maybe that would be of use if similar problem happens in the future...